# Kanji identification?

Tags: kanji

What does the Kanji next to the bar at the bottom right hand side of the screen mean in this video? (The small bar, not the larger one): http://youtu.be/qIKNRmdEx5E?t=20s - The bar that it's next to is a curse (or fever) meter, though I had looked up both of these words previously and this kanji didn't ever seem to appear. If it helps, for context, here's a link to the character's wiki page: http://www.dustloop.com/wiki/index.php?title=Arakune_(BBCP)

Comment: http://jisho.org/kanji/radicals/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Fire", "folding chair" and "mouth" is [「烙」](http://jisho.org/kanji/details/%E7%83%99).

Comment: Interesting. Thanks :) Had been wondering for a while now.

Comment: I suppose it's probably obvious, but 夂 doesn't really signify *folding chair*.  Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams is using that label as a part of a mnemonic, it seems.

Comment: @snailboat: Not an unpopular mnemonic; many sites, Wikipedia and Denshi Jisho included, call radical 66 that or something similar.

Comment: Oh, the reason I couldn't find "folding chair" anywhere is I looked up radical 34, not 66.  It's actually graphically the same as 夂 (radical 34 *winter*), not 攵 (radical 66 *hit, strike*).

Comment: So it is, so it is...